# how to make to position a small image on top of a parent image in css

Tags: html, css

I have a web page design (it is an image) , I embedded it in an html and to display it and the css code is like this

```css
.imageMain {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  /* For 100% screen height */
  width: 100vw;
  /* For 100% screen width */
}

img#homeinactive {
  position: relative;
  top: -960px;
  left: 750px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<img class="imageMain" src="images/mainphoto.png" />
<a href="index.php"><img id="homeinactive" class="ontopPhoto" src="images/navHeader/ontopphoto.jpg" /></a>
```

Now I need to put a small image image on top of that image which will serve as a button that will
redirect a user somewhere. the problem is, only the parent image follows the screen size, and it actually stretches automatically no matter what the size of the screen because of my .imageMain css class.

the small image is being misplace when I change screen size, any idea what to put in the css to make it stay like in the middle top no matter what screen size it will be..take note, this small image is on top of main image..here's my css, it's wrong

here's the html

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: please create a code snippet so we can help you.. thanks

Comment: Hi , I added the html code at the bottom

Comment: @sasori, You mean like this?? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/poJWwzB or like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/NWqagPE

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative
}
.imageMain {
    height: 100vh; /* For 100% screen height */
    width:  100vw; /* For 100% screen width */
    object-fit: cover;
}

img#homeinactive {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top:0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="imageMain" src="images/mainphoto.png" />
        <a href="index.php"><img id="homeinactive" class="ontopPhoto" src="images/navHeader/ontopphoto.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: how to auto adjust the "top" property ? ,

Comment: Same way like the left property, top:50% then you add transform: translate(-50%,-50%) instead of translateX

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using flex. Wrap your second image in a div and use `justify content: center;` and it will always be in center.

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/psparthsahni/50e9nuzh/

Comment: do i need to use bootstrap for that ?

Comment: No, you don't!!